# Webscraping jTable with hidden columns?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, jtable, screen-scraping

I am currently trying to setup a webscraper in Python for the following webpage:

https://understat.com/team/Juventus/2018

specifically for the 'team-players jTable'

I have managed to scrape the table successfully with BeautifulSoup and selenium, but there are hidden columns (accessible via the options popup window) that I can't initialize and include in my scraping.

Anyone know how to change this?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import re
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import re
import random
import datetime


base_url = 'https://understat.com/team/Juventus/2018'
url = base_url
data = requests.get(url)
html = data.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/kylecaron/Desktop/souptest/chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

headers = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'players jTable'}).find('table').find_all('th',attrs={'class':'sort'})

headers_list = [header.get_text(strip=True) for header in headers]

body = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'players jTable'}).table.tbody


all_rows_list = []
for tr in body.find_all('tr'):
    row = tr.find_all('td')
    current_row = []
    for item in row:
        current_row.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
    all_rows_list.append(current_row)

headers_list = ['№', 'Player', 'Positions', 'Apps', 'Min', 'G', 'A', 'Sh90', 'KP90', 'xG', 'xA', 'xG90', 'xA90']

xg_df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows_list, columns=headers_list)
```

If you navigate to the website, there are hidden table columns such as 'XGChain'. I want all of these hidden elements scraped, but having trouble doing it.

Best,
Kyle

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please provide your code. And more explanation of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You could still use BeautifulSoup to iterate through the `tr` and `td` tags, but I always find pandas much easier to get tables, as it does the work for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://understat.com/team/Juventus/2018'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Click the Options Button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="team-players"]/div[1]/button/i').click()

# Click the fields that are hidden
hidden = [7, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
for val in hidden:
    x_path = '//*[@id="team-players"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[%s]/div[2]/label' %val
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path).click()

# Appy the filter    
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="team-players"]/div[2]/div[3]/a[2]').click()

# get the tables in source
tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
data = tables[1]
data.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 22':"Yellow_Cards", "Unnamed: 23":"Red_Cards"})


driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (data.columns)
Index(['№', 'Player', 'Pos', 'Apps', 'Min', 'G', 'NPG', 'A', 'Sh90', 'KP90',
       'xG', 'NPxG', 'xA', 'xGChain', 'xGBuildup', 'xG90', 'NPxG90', 'xA90',
       'xG90 + xA90', 'NPxG90 + xA90', 'xGChain90', 'xGBuildup90',
       'Yellow_Cards', 'Red_Cards'],
      dtype='object')



print (data)
       №                 Player    ...     Yellow_Cards  Red_Cards
0    1.0      Cristiano Ronaldo    ...                2          0
1    2.0        Mario Mandzukic    ...                3          0
2    3.0           Paulo Dybala    ...                1          0
3    4.0  Federico Bernardeschi    ...                2          0
4    5.0         Blaise Matuidi    ...                2          0
5    6.0      Rodrigo Bentancur    ...                5          1
6    7.0          Juan Cuadrado    ...                2          0
7    8.0       Leonardo Bonucci    ...                1          0
8    9.0         Miralem Pjanic    ...                4          0
9   10.0           Sami Khedira    ...                0          0
10  11.0      Giorgio Chiellini    ...                1          0
11  12.0          Medhi Benatia    ...                2          0
12  13.0          Douglas Costa    ...                2          1
13  14.0               Emre Can    ...                2          0
14  15.0           Mattia Perin    ...                1          0
15  16.0      Mattia De Sciglio    ...                0          0
16  17.0      Wojciech Szczesny    ...                0          0
17  18.0        Andrea Barzagli    ...                0          0
18  19.0            Alex Sandro    ...                3          0
19  20.0         Daniele Rugani    ...                1          0
20  21.0             Moise Kean    ...                0          0
21  22.0           João Cancelo    ...                2          0
22   NaN                    NaN    ...               36          2

[23 rows x 24 columns]
```